# Force keeping app window on top - Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, plist, info.plist

Earlier i used Afloat for this but now it seems to be dead...

Is there any alive software or any simple "handy" way to force keeping app window on top over others (including fullscreen apps)

I can imagine this can be done with adding something to plist files inside .app like

```
<!-- Info.plist -->

<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true />
```

for showing app over any fullscreen app (with keystroke)

Google didn't help me much (

Comment: The ability to set the window level remains. Show the code you use that previously worked and what behaviour/errors you now get.

Comment: @CRD i didn't use any code for this. just app named Afloat

Comment: Afloat still works for Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2: First download and install [SIMBL 0.9.9](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php), and then download and install [Afloat for Mac 2.4](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22237/afloat).

Answer (score 2):

Set the level of your mainWindow as

```
[_window setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];
```

Comment: is it possible to set it for existing app? like Skype, i don't know.. how? thanks